# What is the best practices to backup and restore full and partial database with SQL Server 2012 and C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, smo

How can I do the following with C#:

- Completely backup an existing database.
- Partially backup an existing database.
- Completely restore an existing database from a backup file.
- Partially restore an existing database from a backup file.

My database saves images on the **HARDDISK** sometimes I need to backup and restore the database without the stored Images (might be 50 GB).

I need partially backup that execluding the FILESTREAM data 
(The saved files should be not included in the backup file).

I need partially restore that retrive the database without FILESTREAM data (The stored files should be not restored).

What is the best practices to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Remmber you need the following assemblies:
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended

More info http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

 public class SQLServerTools
 {
      public static void SqlBackup(
           // Sql Server name.
        string serverName,
           // The database name on which the backup operation runs.
        string databaseName,
           // The desired backup filename.
        string destinationBackupFilename,
           // this if you want to back partial database without files 
    bool partial)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(
             "Backup on the server {0} the database {1} to the file {2}",
             serverName,
             databaseName,
             destinationBackupFilename);

           // Connect to default sql server instance.
           var sqlServer = GetSqlServer(serverName);

           // Define a Backup object variable.
           var sqlBackup = new Backup { Database = databaseName, };

           // Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up.
           if (partial)
           {
                sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Files;
                sqlBackup.DatabaseFileGroups.Add("PRIMARY");
           }
           else
           {
                sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
           }

           // Declare a BackupDeviceItem.
           var deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationBackupFilename, DeviceType.File);

           // Add the device to the Backup object.
           sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);

           sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
           sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = false;

           // Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup.
           sqlBackup.Incremental = false;
           sqlBackup.PercentCompleteNotification = 1;

           // Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.
           sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

           sqlBackup.PercentComplete += ProgressEventHandler;
           sqlBackup.Complete += ProcessCompleted;

           // Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server.
           sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);

           // Remove the backup device from the Backup object.
           sqlBackup.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);

           // Disconnect and dispose the connection.
           sqlServer.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
      }


      public static void SqlRestore(
           // Sql Server name.
        string serverName,
           // The backup file directory.
        string backupFilePath,
           // The database directory.
        string databaseFolder,
           // The desired restored database name.
        string destinationDatabaseName,
           // The backup filename.
        string backupFilename,
           // The database log name.
        string databaseLogFileName,
           // This will restore the database in partial mode for more info about partial check in the stackoverflow
        bool partial)
      {
           // Current console cursor position.

           //Define a Backup object variable.
           var sqlRestore = new Restore
                              {
                                   Database = destinationDatabaseName,
                                   NoRecovery = false,
                                   ReplaceDatabase = true,

                                   // Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up.
                                   Action = RestoreActionType.Database
                              };

           var sqlServer = GetSqlServer(serverName);

           // If the backup directory not found then get the default.
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseFolder))
           {
                const string SqlDataDirectory = "DATA";
                databaseFolder = sqlServer.InstallDataDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + SqlDataDirectory;
           }

           // Declare a BackupDeviceItem
           var deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(
             backupFilePath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + backupFilename,
             DeviceType.File);

           const string SqlMdfExtention = ".mdf";
           const string SqlLdfLogExtention = "_log.ldf";

           var dataFileLocation = databaseFolder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + destinationDatabaseName + SqlMdfExtention;
           var logFileLocation = databaseFolder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + destinationDatabaseName + SqlLdfLogExtention;

           sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(destinationDatabaseName, dataFileLocation));
           sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseLogFileName, logFileLocation));

           sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
           sqlRestore.ContinueAfterError = false;

           sqlRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 1;
           sqlRestore.PercentComplete += ProgressEventHandler;

           if (partial)
           {
                sqlRestore.Partial = true;
                sqlRestore.ContinueAfterError = true;
           }

           sqlRestore.Complete += ProcessCompleted;

           sqlServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 60 * 60;

           // Add the device to the Restore object.
           sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);

           // Run SqlRestore to perform the database restore on the instance of SQL Server.
           sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);

           var database = sqlServer.Databases[destinationDatabaseName];
           database.SetOnline();

           // Remove the restore device from the restore object.
           sqlRestore.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);

           // Disconnect and dispose the connection.
           sqlServer.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
      }

      private static Server GetSqlServer(string servername)
      {
           // Define Server connection
           var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(servername);
           var sqlServer = new Server(serverConnection);
           sqlServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 60 * 60;
           return sqlServer;
      }

      private static void ProgressEventHandler(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
      {
           Console.Write(e.Percent);
      }

      private static void ProcessCompleted(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
      {
           // Write if any error is exist.
           Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
      }
 }
}
```